# 100 amp sub panel for garage

Tags: wire

Hi I am look to run 100 amp sub panel to my shop from my 200 amp panel in my basement. It about 175 ft in middle of both panel box .
I was looking for someone help me out on wire size and what I would need to do it ?

Comment: There are many very similar questions on the site  use search with “100 amp sub”

Comment: What are your actual anticipated loads? Sizing for 100 (or 80, derated for continuous) amp loads will typically oversize your wires quite a bit from reality. Use aluminum, and tell us if it's going overhead or underground or what...2 AWG aluminum might be a good bet, or big enough for any reasonable load, and some unreasonable ones.

Comment: I take it this shop space is in another, detached building?